# Xubuntu Can't access encrypted home folder

Tags: xubuntu, encryption, home-directory

I'm panicking, and I will just tell you the basics, I couldn't access my home folder because linux crashed, I was stupid deleted a few files and now I can't boot into linux. The only thing I have is the /home folder that has all the files I need to recover, but the problem is the entire disk + home folder is encrypted but I do have the passwords, PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: How about using a live CD?

Answer (score 1):

You should boot a Live CD and then try to mount your home directory. Maybe this guide can help you?

http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/

There is also a page on the Ubuntu Wiki with lots of information.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory